# Interactive pie Chart that works on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, pie-chart, css3pie

Please check the following link:-http://developerz.in/wheel/index.html

I need the same wheel that should work On safari.
right now it is coded in flash. 
I have tried it using HTML and CSS3.
And it is very complicated using jQuery and JavaScript.
Please suggest ways.

Please consider the gradients at the end of the slices.
the slow animation effect on hover.

I appreciate your time.

Comment: Which Javascript charting libraries have you looked at so far?

Comment: Hi Alex I have looked at chart.js and raphael.js. in raphael.js I have created the pie chart and on hover event is also working fine. But I am facing problem in putting the gradient on each slice.

Comment: I would use https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart 
Should work fine in all browsers

Comment: @RajatSharma You need to set the `fill` attribute of each segment of the chart with a gradient at the correct angle. Can you show me your current raphael.js code in a jsfiddle?